# Traveling to Croatia on a D-type visa with residence permit from Hungary

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork, croatia, hungary

I am an Indian student studying in Hungary. I have a single entry D-type Schengen visa with a residence permit issued from Hungary. Can I visit Croatia for 5 days and travel back to Hungary? I am confused because while my visa is single entry, I also have a residence permit which allows me to enter Croatia. But can I re-enter Hungary?

Answer (score 1):

Your D visa is no longer relevant, since you have received your residence permit card.

So yes, you can undertake this trip using your passport and residence permit card.